# Difficulty accessing widgets after loading interface from ui file with loadUi()

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I like the idea of using the loadUi() method in PyQt to load in a QtDesigner interface file as I'm often changing the ui file and don't want to be constantly converting it to a py file.

However, I've been having difficulty understanding how to access the different widgets and views in my ui file. The below shows how I'm loading in the ui:

```
class MyClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        ui = uic.loadUi('MyUserInterface.ui',self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainapplication = MyClass()
    mainapplication.show()
    app.exec_()
```

It displays fine, but I was expecting that I would be able to access the elements of the GUI by something along the lines of...

```
ui.sampleButton.makeDraggable()
```

My question is, how can I access the various elements within my GUI?

Edit 1: I Also have tried to without assigning the uic.load call to ui.  When accessing as shown below, I can access some of the properties through using Ui_MainWindow.  However, it throws an error

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainapplication = MyClass()
    mainapplication.Ui_MainWindow.graphicsView.acceptDrops(True)
    mainapplication.show()
    app.exec_()
```

The error i get is...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Users\Me\workspaces\com.samplesoftware.software\src\SoftwareView\MyClass.py", line 17, in <module>
  mainapplication.Ui_MainWindow.graphicsView.acceptDrops(True)
  AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'Ui_MainWindow'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The [loadUi](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/designer.html#the-uic-module) function takes a ui file path as the first argument, and a base-instance as the second argument.

The base-instance should be the same Qt class as the top-level widget in the UI. This is because `loadUi` will insert all the UI into the base-instance, and may need to call some of its methods in doing so. All the child widgets that are defined in the UI will end up as attributes of the base-instance.

So you should call `loadUi` like this in your `__init__`:

```
class MyClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('MyUserInterface.ui', self)
```

And you should then be able to access `graphicsView` like this:

```
        self.graphicsView.setAcceptDrops(True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had actually tried this as well, but found I still have the same problem.  The only options available to me in self are QtGui, QtCore and Ui_MainWindow.  I've updated my question for some additional info.

Comment: @Flaminator. Sorry - I just copied and pasted your example code without checking it properly. Looks like you need to fix your `super` call (see my updated answer). Then you should be able to do `mainapplication.graphicsView.setAcceptDrops(True)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ekhumoro.  I actually found the reason was related to my trying to cal lthe MainWindow before it exists... I've posted an answer, thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert it to a .py file but you definitely have to name them to access them, otherwise you need to know what the sampleButton is called in the ui file.

you can simply rename the sampleButton to my_btn and access it..

Comment: I named the button sampleButton in the ui file. SampleButton is just a name I gave it for the example.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason why was because I was trying to call the Ui_MainWindow prior to running app.exec_().  After moving the Ui_MainWindow call to the end it does work.  I'm guessing, and it does make sense in hindsight, the MainWindow needs to exist before its properties can be altered.

Comment: At first I thought I had corrected the problem, but then I realized that puting the call after the app.exec_() call was just delaying the call of the Ui_MainWindow.  After the program closes down I get the same error.  Still not sure what the source of it is...